# Fibbonaci recursive code returns wrong value, always the next number

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this simple code. For example I send 5 and expect the 5th number to be returned, which is 5, but it returns 8 instead which is the 6th fib number.
I tried looking up other examples, they look the same, but when i compile returns wrong answer.

```
int fibbonaci(int n) {

    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    return fibbonaci(n - 1) + fibbonaci(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: The fib sequence is `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8` where those are "indexes" `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Looks like you got the 5th "index" to me. Perhaps you need to clarify what you mean by "5th number."

Answer (score 4):

`if (n <= 1) return 1;` -> `if (n <= 1) return n;`

In your original example, where you returned `1`, you indicated that there exists a `0`th Fibonacci number equal to `1` (imagine what `fibbonaci(2)` would execute as - the sum of `fibbonaci(1)` and `fibbonaci(0)`, which both return `1` in your example). You should treat it like a `0`, if you wish to take the described approach.

Comment: It works for numbers from 1 and above. But 0 returns 0, while it should return 1. That's why I didn't use return n. Or am I misunderstanding something. Doesn't it go 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 and so on?

Comment: ***Or am I misunderstanding something*** You are misunderstanding. fib(0) is supposed to be 0. https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html

Comment: If `0`th number is `1`, then `1 1 2 3 5 8 13` sequence means that index `5` corresponds to value `8`, which your original example showed.

Answer (score 2):

Your function:

```
fib(0) -> 1
fib(1) -> 1
fib(2) -> fib(1) + fib(0) = 1 + 1 = 2
fib(3) -> fib(2) + fib(1) = 2 + 1 = 3
```

and so on.

See if you can figure what is wrong and what you need to change.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function should be named at least like `fibonacci` instead of `fibbonaci`.

You should use as the function parameter an unsigned integer type instead of the signed integer type `int`.

The first fibonacci value returned by your function is incorrect. The function returns 1 instead of 0 due to this statement

```
if (n <= 1) return 1;
```

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr unsigned long long fibonacci( unsigned int n ) 
{
    return n < 2 ? n :  fibonacci( n - 1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 );
}

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << fibonacci( i ) << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```